# data-image-src(Parallax.js) not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use Parallax.js but that not working correctly.
I have used this library several times but this time `<div />`expands `style="background-image: ......"` automatically X( Probably, other script prevented it.

```
 <div class="parallax" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="./assets/img/top.jpeg" data-speed="0.6" data-position="center top">
 </div>
```

currently:

```
 <div class="parallax" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="./assets/img/top.jpeg" data-speed="0.6" data-position="center top" style="background: url("./assets/img/top.jpeg") center top / cover;">
 </div>
```

should be:

```
 <div class="parallax" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="./assets/img/top.jpeg" data-speed="0.6" data-position="center top">
 </div>
```

Comment: After the page loads you can remove the `style` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the `style` property once the DOM is loaded.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',  () => {
    const div = document.querySelector('.parallax');
    div.removeAttribute('style');
});
```

```html
<div class="parallax" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="./assets/img/top.jpeg" data-speed="0.6" data-position="center top">
</div>
```